# Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

Why is `Json Request Behavior` needed?

If I want to restrict the `HttpGet` requests to my action I can decorate the action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    return Json("Secrets");
}

// Instead of:
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    return Json("Secrets", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Why isn't `[HttpPost]`sufficient?
Why the framework "bugs" us with the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for every `JsonResult` that we have. If I want to deny get requests I'll add the `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625671/why-are-get-requests-returning-json-disallowed-by-default (although I found this one searching for my own question :))

Comment: Because GET is supposed to be idempotent whereas POST is not. By making GETs -> POSTs, you change the semantics of the interface.

Comment: Because your code would look too clean if you didn't have to add crufty args everywhere.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

MVC defaults to `DenyGet` to protect you against a very specific attack involving JSON requests to improve the liklihood that the implications of allowing `HTTP GET` exposure are considered in advance of allowing them to occur.

This is opposed to afterwards when it might be too late.

Note: If your action method does not return sensitive data, then it should be safe to allow the get.

**Further reading from my Wrox ASP.NET MVC3 book**

> By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to
>   an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. If you need to send JSON in
>   response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by
>   using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as the second parameter to the Json
>   method. However, there is a chance a malicious user can gain access to
>   the JSON payload through a process known as JSON Hijacking. You do not
>   want to return sensitive information using JSON in a GET request. For
>   more details, see Phil's post at
>   [http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx/](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) or [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers/16880162#16880162)
>
> Haack, Phil (2011). Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 (Wrox Programmer to
>   Programmer) (Kindle Locations 6014-6020). Wrox. Kindle Edition.

**Related StackOverflow question**

[With most recents browsers (starting with Firefox 21, Chrome 27, or IE 10), this is no more a vulnerability.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers/16880162#16880162)

Comment: But the question remains: Why isn't [HttpPost] sufficient?

Comment: I think it is sufficient. You only need AllowGet when you want to allow the data to pass as the result of a HttpGet. DenyGet is the default, if you invoke Json(data) with 1 parameter.

Comment: This is my question. Why the framework "bugs" us with the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for every JsonResult that I have. If I want to deny get request I'll add the `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: I think it's because not a lot of people are aware of this obscure vulnerability. You say if you want to deny the request, you will do it with [HttpPost]. However the MVC authors are giving you a layer of protection out of the box against this kind of attack. Since you need to make effort to add the 2nd argument, you should take that time to consider what data you are exposing, and how sensitive it is.

Comment: So now we clutter up our API and add verb confusion to "RESTful" interfaces to get around a potential CLIENT driven vulnerability?  This seems terrible...but I appreciate the discussion.

Comment: How is GET more vulnerable than POST?

Comment: @AndersLindén because script tags that point to a URL don't load those remote scripts via POST, so the attack would not succeed because the server only accepts POST requests for that data.

Comment: I think the fact that Microsoft protects programmers this way out of the box is certainly not a bad thing, but the *way* they've done it is rather annoying. The second argument is a rather lengthy enum member and it clutters code. They could easily have made an overload that accepts a `bool`, or even another method like `JsonGet(...)` for example. People would still wonder why it's there and learn about the vulnerability / risk. Sure, you can make those yourself on a BaseController, but I don't like having a BaseController at all personally.

Comment: If you're annoyed just subclass it

Comment: Ironically, modern browsers are not longer vulnerable to the JSON hijacking issue that prompted the MVC team to include that safeguard. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers.

Answer (score 64):

To make it easier for yourself you could also create an actionfilterattribute

```
public class AllowJsonGetAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;

        if (jsonResult == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Action does not return a JsonResult, 
                                                   attribute AllowJsonGet is not allowed");

        jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;            

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and use it on your action

```
[AllowJsonGet]
public JsonResult MyAjaxAction()
{
    return Json("this is my test");
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you could set this as default filter in RegisterGlobalFilters: filters.Add(new AllowJsonGetAttribute()). But then you have to remove the Exception since the Filter will be applied for all action-methods.

Answer (score 9):

By default Jsonresult "Deny get"

Suppose if we  have method like below

```
  [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult amc(){}
```

By default it "Deny Get".

In the below method

```
public JsonResult amc(){}
```

When you need to allowget or use get ,we have to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.

```
public JsonResult amc()
{
 return Json(new Modle.JsonResponseData { Status = flag, Message = msg, Html = html }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Improving upon the answer of @Arjen de Mooij a bit by making the 
AllowJsonGetAttribute applicable to mvc-controllers (not just individual action-methods):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public sealed class AllowJsonGetAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var jsonResult = context.Result as JsonResult;
        if (jsonResult == null) return;

        jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
        if (jsonResult == null) return;

        jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need it.

If your action has the `HttpPost` attribute, then you do not need to bother with setting the `JsonRequestBehavior` and use the overload without it. There is an overload for each method without the `JsonRequestBehavior` enum. Here they are:

**Without JsonRequestBehavior**

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data);
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType);
protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding);
```

**With JsonRequestBehavior**

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior);
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, 
                                   JsonRequestBehavior behavior);
protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, 
    Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior);
```