# mvc client access without browser or view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 C# application that I want to allow a client to access through code (no browser or view).  The client will send a user ID which will be used to look up a record and three fields will be returned. Both the incoming and outgoing data are sensitive information so I need a solution that is secure.  The application is running on a site with SSL (https), will this protect me from JSON hijacking if I use a JSON solution as two answers have suggested?

```
public ActionResult InAction(string id)
{ 
  // code to retrieve record and return three fields field1, field2, field3

  return (what would go here?)
}
```

Can I even use a Controller Action to handle this?  Do I need a full blown webservice to do this, if so any links to good MVC tutorials would be helpful?

The client works in ASP (webforms) and is talking about a responder page with key value pairs, how would I do the equivalent in MVC.

Any help on getting me going is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

**UPDATE:** I’ve marked Brett’s JSON suggestion as the answer.  I am returning a string (not an array) and the entire transaction is taking place over a SSL connection so I believe the possibility of JSON hijacking is not an issue.

```
  string response = field1 + "," + field2 + "," + field3;
  return Json(response), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet; }
```

If I'm mistaken on that please let me know.

Comment: You might want to use a wcf service with ws* protocols which gives JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nikeaa mentions, just create an action within you controller that returns a JsonResult

```
public JsonResult InAction(string id)
{
    // get some object from repository
    var repository = new ObjectRepository();
    var returnObj = repository.GetObject(id);
    return Json(returnObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You will need to specify JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet to override the default .DenyGet.   This opens up a security vulnerability when returning JSON with a GET request though.   [See this StackOverflow answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464685/787317)

Comment: Thanks, Brett.  I should have mentioned that the site running the application is https (ssl) and that I will be returning sensitive inforamtion.  Since I cannot use [HttpPost] on the JsonResult I have to use .AlllowGet.  I don't follow your comment that I shoud use it for security reasons, isn't .AllowGet what makes it vulnerable to JSON hijacking?  The link says 'You do not want to return sensitive information using JSON in a GET request.'  How could I securely return the sensitive information to the client?  Will SSL protect me against JSON hijacking?

Comment: @Joe, I have edited my response, I was just stating you need that parameter to override the default behaviour. I'm no expert, but I would try to avoid sending sensitive data to the client unless they were authenticated, I would imagine over SSL is better. Also to avoid the JSON hijacking, I think one method would be to ensure the response is encapsulated in an object rather than being an array.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer.  I thought the phrasing on .AllowGet was still confusing.  I took the liberty of editing your response to make it clearer.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had upvoted but not clicked the arrow.  Done now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the the format you want to return the data in. For example, if you wanted to return the data in JSON format, you could use the following:

```
return (Json(userResultModel));
```

You would probably also want to change the method's return type to JsonResult.