# ResponseRedirect as Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you make a controller function that returns ResponseRedirect to instead return that ResponseRedirect as Json object?

I want to do something like this

```
 return Json(new { url = RedirectToAction("AccountMyProducts", "Account"), redirect = "true" });
```

To get the redirect url in my jsonobject.

Comment: do you want the client to redirect or return json data?

Comment: I want the client to return the url from the redirectAction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do like this

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

explanation : function returns the type of JsonResult, which is inherited by ActionResult.

1. `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` :
    From this Answer  [why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

> This is to protect against a very specific attack with JSON requests
>   that return data using HTTP GET.
>
> Basically, if your action method does not return sensitive data, then
>   it should be safe to allow the get.
>
> However, MVC puts this in with DenyGet as the default to protect you
>   against this attack. It makes you consider the implications of what
>   data you are exposing, before you decide to expose it over HTTP GET

if you are planning to redirect based on json data

```
return Json(new 
{ 
    redirectUrl = Url.Action("AccountMyProducts", "Account"), 
    isredirection= true 
});
```

in Jquery success  call back function, do like this

```
$.ajax({
.... //some other stuffs including url, type, content type. 

//then for success function. 
success: function(json) {
    if (json.isredirection) {
        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
return Json(new { url = "Account/AccountMyProducts", redirect = "true" });
```

It is worth noting that `RedirectToAction(...)` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` which is evaluated by the method which calls your controller action, rather than returning the actual URL straight away.