# How could my MVC JSON action be called with GET if my only use is with POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC action that is returning JSON.  The only place I am calling that action is from one page with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
 });
```

**The page and this AJAX call are working fine from the user and testing perspective.  However I found *one error* in the log** saying:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

and indicating my "actionUrl" in the `SCRIPT_NAME` server variable.  The `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET` and `QUERY_STRING` is empty. There is also a `HTTP_REFERER` server variable which indicates it is coming from the page with the above `$.ajax()` call, so it doesn't seem likely it's someone is accessing the JSON action manually.

The only thing I have come up with is that something strange might happen if the user hits the `Back` or `Refresh` buttons in the browser, but that doesn't seem right.

Is there any solid explanation of how that **one** GET request could have been generated?

Comment: What triggers the ajax call? Is the URL used in a form somewhere, or an `<a>` tag?

Comment: The ajax call is in an event handler that I provided to a 3rd party control

Comment: Does your controller action have [HttpPost] or [HttpGet] above it? You can place these attributes right above the public ActionResult ...

Comment: No it doesn't have either of those attributes.

Comment: It will default to GET. Place [HttpPost] above it. See what you get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed

Comment: "It will default to GET"... Really?  I am specifying POST explicitly in my $.ajax call!

Comment: @DylanHayes, I don't see how that linked question addresses my question of "How could a GET request have been generated when my $.ajax code specifies POST"?

Comment: Lets back it up a second. Have you set a break point on your controller action, and the ajax call is hitting the action or is it not? Are you having trouble connecting to the action or returning data?

Comment: @blackops, if I put the [HttpPost] there, and a GET request is still generated, then all that will be accomplished is to get a different error.  That does not answer the question of where is the GET request coming from

Comment: @blackops, as I said in my question, everything is working fine for our users and in my testing.  If I put a breakpoint there I see that it is coming in as a POST and returning the JSON with no problem.  The only issue is figuring out that 1 error in my log.

Comment: Note that anybody can see the URLs that your client is using, and simply typing in the URL of that action will cause a GET transaction to be run from the browser.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think they are typing it in because (as indicated in my question) I am seeing an HTTP_REFERER in the log entry

Comment: Well, strictly speaking you can't really trust REFERER, but I agree that it's unlikely.  But any use of that URL as an implicit link would also cause a GET, and you'd get a REFERER then too. Or if it's in a `<form>` without a "method" attribute.

Comment: @Pointy, it is only used from the $.ajax code... nowhere else on the site

Comment: I agree it's "possible" someone used Fiddler or some other technique to generate this request, but it came from an authenticated user and it's VERY unlikely, so I am trying to figure out a more likely cause

Comment: Is it happening every time the request is made? Or it occurred only once?

Comment: @FelipeMiosso, as stated in the question (in bold :) "The page is working fine. However I found one error in the log"

Comment: @JoelFan sorry i misunderstood the question, i thought you were asking why it was prompting you to use the allowget requestbehavior

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers? Do you have any <img src=''> anywhere?

Comment: No <img src...>.  It only hapenned one time.  It was on IE 8 / Windows XP (ack!)

Comment: Maybe caching issues on the client? Did the javascript changed (used to do a get instead of a post?)?

Comment: @rivarolle, no there was no change... this is the first time the code has gone live

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what probably happened. If someone is looking at the Network tab of the Developer Tools in their browser, they can see the file being called. If they right click the file and "Open in new tab", the page will be opened with a GET, and you will see the error message. Someone was probably testing and manually opened the link.

Answer (score -2):

Probably $.ajax uses some get requests by default, use $.post() instead of it.

```
$.post( url, function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: You are saying that $.ajax will do a GET sometimes, even if I say type: 'POST' ?  The jquery doc explicitly says that $.post() is just a shorthand for $.ajax({ type: 'POST' })

Comment: Just was a soppositon from memory, but the code is corret if u want fix that warning. You are wellcome.