# Return data LINQ in Json

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How to return data LINQ in Json
Use this, but no work

```
    public ActionResult GenerateShop()
    {
        LinqDataContext context = new LinqDataContext();
        IEnumerable<shops> shops = context.shops;            
        return Json(shops.ToList());
    }
```

This is error "When serializing an object of type "RentApp.Models.bikes" found a circular reference"
Why he writes bikes, when I shop?
It is worked

```
var json = Json(shops.ToList());
```

But no work **retrun**
When I create the model manually everything works fine, but me need LINQ

```
public List<Shops> ListShop()
    {
        List<Shops> shopList = new List<Shops>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = this.connfiguration;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM shops", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();                    
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Shops shop = new Shops();
                    shop.id = (int)rdr["id"];
                    shop.name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                    shopList.Add(shop);
                }
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
        return shopList;
    }
```

In controller

```
    public ActionResult GenerateShop()
    {
        model.shops = this.rent.ListShop();
        return Json(model.shops);
    }
```

Comment: "no work" is a *horrible* description of your problem. Please describe exactly the behavior you get and what you are expecting to happen instead.

Comment: I do not know, return client server error 500,  but if I create a model by hand, everything works fine

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `shops` class please?

Comment: **shop** Class VisualStudio generates self, based on a database

Comment: The problem is that when you return shops, you most probably have a property called `Bikes` inside it which contains many bikes which in return contains a property called `Shop` which reference back the shop you are trying to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you return shops, you most probably have a property called Bikes inside it which contains many bikes which in return contains a property called Shop which reference back the shop you are trying to return thus causing a circular reference and without further guidelines, will cause the serializer to go on in an infinite loop.

Simplest possible option is to project the required properties from your `Shop` entity to an anonymous type and pass that to the Json method.

```
LinqDataContext context = new LinqDataContext();
IEnumerable<shops> shops = context.shops;            
return Json(shops.select(x=>new{x.ShopID,
                                x.ShopProperty2,
                                x.ShopName,
                                ...
                                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i havnt tried though..

```
public ActionResult GenerateShop()
    {
        LinqDataContext context = new LinqDataContext();
        var shops = context.shops.ToList();            
        return Json(shops, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

for more reference see here:-

[Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you want, but you have to add JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet to return the JSON data.

Few suggstion use context for one time. create context type in globally then use it.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData()
{
 LinqDataContext context = new LinqDataContext();
        var shops = context.shops.ToList();            
        return Json(shops,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I am use, but no work

Comment: This is error "When serializing an object of type "RentApp.Models.bikes" found a circular reference"