# Json response doesn't appears in success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using ajax call with Jquery but it doesn't look to be right.

I call a controller:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "http://urlWithpropperParams.com",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.isEdited)
                        {
                            alert('No error');
                            window.location.href = 'http://myurl.com';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('Error');
                            //html(result.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

That controller is called and retuen Json Object (I put a breakpoint on it and it looks fine):

```
public JsonResult EditAuthority(string id, bool value)
        {
...
            return Json(new { isEdited = true, message = "" });
        }
```

The success part of the jquery ajax call must make something, but nothing is happening, and I see no error on console in my browser.

What is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing an HTTP GET with a JSON payload.

> By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to
>   an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. If you need to send JSON in
>   response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by
>   using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as the second parameter to the Json
>   method.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464685/84395

Try adding `AllowGet` to your response:

```
return Json(new { isEdited = true, message = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```