# Understanding nuances of POST and GET in a better way

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am an ASP.NET developer. First I tried this:

```
 $.getJSON('/Admin/GetPrelimsByJob/109', function (data) {
                var template = $('#optionTemplate').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            });
```

With a controller method signature of:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPrelimsByJob(int jobId)
```

My first error was that the ID was not being parsed and discovered via the ASP.NET engine.

For testing purposes I took a step back and stopped passing an id:

```
$.getJSON('/Admin/GetPrelimsByJob', function (data) {
                var template = $('#optionTemplate').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            });
```

With a controller signature of;
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPrelimsByJob()

My second error was:
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

I understand I can set the JsonRequestBehavior to GET to fix this but why is this an issue, why is my response different than if I were to do a POST request.

And finally, to get things to work I did:

```
 $.postJSON('/Admin/GetPrelimsByJob', { jobId: 109 }, function (data) {
                var template = $('#optionTemplate').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            });
```

Where my controller signature was:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetPrelimsByJob(int jobId)
```

And where my jQuery extension was:

```
 $.postJSON('/Admin/GetPrelimsByJob', { jobId: 109 }, function (data) {
                var template = $('#optionTemplate').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            });
```

I knew I get everything working if I switched to a POST request but I am wondering why.

So to recap:
1) Why was my id not being parsed by the ASP.NET engine when passing an id via a GET request.

2)Why do I have to set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet to get my request to allow the JSON data to in the response.

3) Why does a POST just work in this scenario, I am getting data and it seems that the RESTful HTTP action verb GET should be the appropriate choice. Not that I am trying to strictly adhere to REST.

Comment: Could you give more details about the error you got for 1) Also your routing configuration would come handy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) To make you more conscious about security issues involved with serving json via GET for detailed explanation see here: [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464685/155213)

3) By default browsers will not allow you to make cross domain POST's that's why POST's requests are less vulnerable to i.e. [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) than GET requests thus you don't need to set JsonRequestBehavior at all.