# How to access JSON property from MVC controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Calling the Controller

```
action: @Url.Action( "UploadFiles",  "Dokument",  new {  } )
```

Building JSON object with `startTabIndex`

```
public JsonResult UploadFiles()
{
    var foo = 0;
    return Json(new { startTabIndex = foo });
}
```

How can I access the `startTabIndex`property?

```
complete: function (ajaxContext) {
    console.log('ajaxContext: ' + ajaxContext); // not undefined
    console.log(ajaxContext.startTabIndex); // undefined
    startTabIndex = ajaxContext.startTabIndex; // not working
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(ajaxContext)` for us?

Comment: Can you check with `ActionResult` instead of `JsonResult`?

Comment: Object { originalEvent=Event readystatechange, type="complete", timeStamp=1399364010574000, more...} It's many lines, what are you looking for?

Comment: Is `complete` function the [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) complete?

Comment: szpic, it didn't help.

Comment: Hm, and `console.log(arguments)` in the `complete` callback?

Comment: My response from Firefox's firebug: "{"action_success":true,"startTabIndex":0}" and I have the same in Firefox's JSON tap: action_success true startTabIndex 0

Comment: Cerbrus: I am not sure I can paste and show you anything meaningsfull? What are we looking for? This is what I got: [Object { originalEvent=Event readystatechange, type="complete", timeStamp=1399364523919000, more...}, Object[input#wijUpload_1399364518744_input0 property value = "C:\Develop_docs...dekn.doc" attribute value = "null"]]

Comment: I'm trying to find where the actual data went. Does `ajaxContent` contain a `data` property?

Comment: ajaxContext.data is undefined.

Comment: Do I have to tell it that I what the returned datatype to be JSON? Maybe I forgot that?

Comment: Zabavski: No `complete`is from wijupload:
            var upload = $('foo').wijupload(
                    complete: function (ajaxContext) {
})

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting this logic in a separate javascript file that could be referenced from your view. For example, you could store the url into a global javascript variable in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploadFileUrl = '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "FileController")';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

and inside the script make the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: uploadFileUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Your controller action you are invoking that returns a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
    var foo = 0;
    var model = new
    {
        startTabIndex = foo
    };
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: They `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is new for me, I will try that first.

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8464685) for greater details.

Comment: your ajax call, uses type: "GET" and dataType: "json". I don't know what I use because I use the url action helper:  `@Url.Action` . Where can I see? View sourcecode on the page and try found it?
Also I should mention that I have the post attribute on my action `[HttpPost]`. I can't have that and use your "GET" at the same time.

Comment: From your question it seems like you are trying to do an AJAX get since you are returning a json object in your MVC Controller Action.