# ASP.Net AJAX $GetJson function won't get executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I really don't know why but the function(response)-part won't be executed at all - although the Get Method in my Controller gets called by getJSON.

Script:

```
$.getJSON(getUrl, {
        BUID: buID,
        AID: aID,
        LID: lID
    }, function (response) {
        $('#Test').text("TEST");
    })
};
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetMeasures(int buID) {
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

The Text of my span element doesn't get changed into "TEST".

Comment: `It's $('#Test').text("TEST");`

Comment: @LShetty Thanks for your response - but even with $('#Test').text("TEST"); it's not working.

Comment: You really need to explain _it's not working_ as I don't know what _it_ is!

Comment: @LShetty As described in the question I'd like to change a text in my view after the Json response "gets in" - so _it_ means that the call-back function of $.getJSON is not called at all.

Comment: try to change ".text" to ".html" so it should look like this:  $('#Test').html('TEST');

Comment: Put an `alert` inside the function and see if it works. Have an eye on the browser console/network as well to see what activitis take place.

Comment: Even with html instead of text the label didn't change... As I said the call-back function itself isn't called - even alert("Test") doesn't give any output. I rly don't get why - as I said my Controller Method gets definitely called.

Comment: @LShetty I've got it - I just forgot to set the JsonBehaviour to AllowGet - thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send correct parameters:

```
$.getJSON(getUrl, {
        buID: buID
    }, function (response) {
        $('#Test').text("TEST");
    })
};
```

And then you need to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` with JSON return, Also decorate your function with `HttpGet` attribute

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetMeasures(int buID) {
        return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A good read [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)