# Ajax error Typerror: data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: App.CONTEXT_PATH + "/candidate/uploadPhoto",
    fileElementId: 'photoFile',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (!result) {
            return;
        }
        var code = result.code;
        if (code == 1) {
            var fileName = result.data;
            $("#imageFileName").val(fileName);
            $(".display_pic img").attr("src", App.UPLOAD_URL + "/" + fileName);
            alert("Image Path: " + App.UPLOAD_URL + "/" + fileName);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

It popup this error: TypeError: data is undefined. I investigated the response with Firebug and saw the correct reponse as below:

```
{"data":"f95eed76-0fdb-4b45-bbb8-dfae8b7f548awebapp.png","code":1}
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would throw a `TypeError`, even if `data` was undefined in your object, `undefined` would just appear in your input and in your alert, plus, `data` is not the same as `result.data`, and I'm sure that if `result.data` was the cause of the error, then the console would log it as what it is, not as `data`. The error must be happening somewhere else in your code. What line is indicated as the culprit?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed ?

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett: data definitely does not refer to result.data because when I changed the attribute to something else, same error occurs.  The error was shown by alert(errorThrown) in error block.

Comment: @OğuzhanSoykan: Do you suggest to explicitly specify method to be POST?

Comment: no I just suggest specify  `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` on your return statement, if you dont. By the way you can check your action, it should be ActionResult and you return is `new JsonResult(){Data = [your-object], JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet }`

Comment: Hi I have fixed this issue. It is actually die to a subtle issue with the ajax file upload library that I used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure about this, but you could try and store the result info into a variable immediately and then work on that.

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: App.CONTEXT_PATH + "/candidate/uploadPhoto",
        fileElementId: 'photoFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            var temporary = result;
            if (!temporary) {
                return;
            }
            var code = temporary.code;
            if (code == 1) {
                var fileName = temporary.data;
```