# Json return form Controller are not working

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to get json object from string and return it from controller.

In my Controller I have second thing:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPageFilters()
    {
        ...
        ...

        if (settings != null)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(settings.Filters); //Filter is string with json

            return Json(data);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }            
    }
```

and this in my view:

```
    var filterOption;

    $.get('Library/Books/GetPageFilters', null, function(data) {
        filterOption = data;
    }, "json");
```

Controller are called normally, string is deserialized to object... but `function(data)` is not working. Nothing are happening there and I cant get why.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Looks like string to json went wrong.
I tried to save it in database what looks fine i guess, but read it properly is a problem to me.

```
function UpdateFilter() {

    var filterOption = {
        "filterTarget": "Books",
        "filters": [
            { "cancelled": $("#showCancelledFilter").is(':checked') },
            { "completed": $("#showAllFilter").is(':checked') }
        ],
        "page": page,
        "sorting": sorting
    };

    var url = "Library/Books/UpdateFilter";
    $.post(url, { pageFilters: JSON.stringify(filterOption) }, function (data) { });
}
```

seems working fine, but as I told already, from string to json is not ok for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing is happening'? Do you get inside the success handler?

Comment: Because its a GET method. You need `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Does that mean that I actually don't need a `[HttpGet]` ?

Comment: You could make it `[HttpPost]`, but you dont seem to be changing any data, so a GET seems more appropriate

Comment: Thanks, could you please make your comment as an answer so I can mark it? Aslo... I got data in view... but looks loke deserializing went wrong (I got a 4 Arrays (array on each field in json and empty array inside each array)... I will describe in edit, how i tried to dave json in database and then get it from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is marked with the `[HttpGet]` which means you need to change you method to

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

By default, the `JsonRequestBehavior` is set to `DenyGet`

You can read more about this in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

Comment: Thanks. If you have some time, could you please view the edit where is described change json to string and its writing to database, because that I received after deserialization is not what I needed. :(

Comment: Eh, well, will make it as another question :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPageFilters()
    {
        ...
        ...

        if (settings != null)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(settings.Filters); //Filter is string with json

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }            
    }
```