# Why the Ajax http get doesn't retrive json?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I need to retrieve JSON or HTML from my MVC controller by an Ajax call.
The question is why that below doesn't work with a GET request ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST", //It works but doesn't work with GET 
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});

public ActionResult Index()
{
       if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
              ...
              return View(selectedUser);
        }
        return Json(new { Error = Messages.AUTHENTICATIONEXPIRED });
}
```

With HTTP GET it get nothing instead the Json Object. 
The Action method is executed successfully. 
Is there a technical reason that I don't know? is there another way to make it work without making a POST call?
Thanks

Comment: What is happening? An error? Try decorating the action method with `[HttpGet]`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work when you're trying to get it instead of post? Are you getting exception, 404, anything else? Have you tried to debug server-side, is method you've shown called? Is there a chance this method has been decorated with [POST] attribute in your real code?

Comment: it just retrieve nothing instead the JSON object. The action is fine, yes sure I debugged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When returning Json through GET, you have to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` :

```
return Json(new { Error = Messages.AUTHENTICATIONEXPIRED }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

More info [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed).