# Why return Json result is Privacy Violation?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, security

I have this code:

```
 public ActionResult Test(string password)
 {
     return Json(TestMethod(password));
 }

 public bool TestMethod (string password)
 {
    return true;
 }
```

But in "return Json(TestMethod(password));" I get a Privacy Violation vulnerability.

Is this due to the fact that I call the method TestMethod in Json()?

Comment: Where do you get this message? This isn't a compiler message. Most likely though, whatever tool you have sees that you have a `password` symbol in the constructor of `JsonResult` and assumes that there may be a problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28718745/2181514

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this is due to the variable being called password.

Its picking up rules from

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Privacy_Violation

You are exposing a password without encryption or hashing.

Comment: Why would that be a privary violation? What does that even mean? It isn't a compiler message

Comment: If I will call TestMethod with password before and than return result in Json - is it fix my problem? Like this "var res = TestMethod(password); return Json(res);"