# Ajax request for asp.net mvc controller returning 500 - internal server error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have these two `select`s on a view:

```
<select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" onchange="carregarCidades()" id="comboEstado">
    ...
</select>

<select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" id="comboCidade">
   ...
</select>
```

The first represents a State, and when I select it I want to execute the `carregarCidades` function to load the cities of that stat and them load them in the other select. Here is the function:

```
function carregarCidades() {
    var url = "@Url.Action("CarregarCidades", "Usuario")";

    var estado = $("#comboEstado").find(":selected").text();

    $.get(url, { pEstado: estado }, function (cidades) {
        $("#comboCidade").html(""); // clear before appending new list 
        $.each(cidade, function (i, cidade) {
            $("#comboCidade").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(cidade.id_cidade).html(cidade.cidade));
        });
    });
}
```

Now, here is the CarregarCidades action in the UsuarioController:

```
public ActionResult CarregarCidades(string pEstado)
{
    string cCidades = oVFP.BuscaCidade(pEstado);

    DataSet dsC = new DataSet();
    dsC.ReadXml(new StringReader(cCidades));

    JsonResult result = Json(dsC.Tables["curretorno"]);
    return result;
}
```

I'm debugging the action and apparently everything is ok:

[image]
[image]

But, after the Action returns the Json result, the callback funcion is not called on the jquery code and I got a 500 internal server error in my console.

Comment: You are saying the server method works fine. Where are you getting the 500 error ? When calling the same action method ? What other information you get in the Response tab of the corresponding request ?

Comment: I'm getting the error at Chrome's console, saying the error is happening in my ajax request.

Comment: Ehsan's answer will fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [`JsonAllowRequestbehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx) parameter to `AllowGet`, by default it is `DenyGet` :

```
JsonResult result = Json(dsC.Tables["curretorno"],JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You can read about [Why it is needed on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed).

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure your method has the `[WebMethod]` attribute above its declaration.

The second thing I would suggest is returning your Json like this:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Generally it is one of or both of these issues that gives you a 500 error.

Edit:

*Declaring it as a `[WebMethod]` may not be necessary.*

Comment: It's mvc we don't need webmethod attribute