# Ajax POST request don't show the alert

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm using this code for delete comment .

but when i delete comment , it not show me alert in success . what's the problem ?

```
function DeleteComment(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/Comment/DeleteComment/" + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    alert("نظر مورد نظر با موفقست حذف گردید");
                } else {
                    alert("خطایی رخ داده ، نظر حذف نشد . لطفا خطا را بررسی کنید");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

** Edit **

```
public JsonResult DeleteComment(int id)
    {
        var deletecomment = _CommentService.CommentByID(id);
        if (_CommentService.RemoveComment(deletecomment))
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show server-side method.

Comment: Is the url correct ? what you get in return ?

Comment: if `data` is a true or false value, just do `if (data)`, also the reason that it dont show might be becasue you dont get the success call, try add an error: call

Comment: Are you sure this request return a success response?

Comment: are you sure its returning with success.

Comment: If your request method is `GET`, you have to use `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet`, like this: `return Json(true,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);`.

Comment: yea . i debug that .  it's return success  .

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai thank you . its work . my method is post , i add `type:POST` and it work . thank you again

Comment: @Kianoush, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai . yea . i know my frinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request method is `GET`, you have to use `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet`, like this:

`return Json(true,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)`;

If you look in the `console`, you will see an error.

> Why do you need JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet ?

This is to protect against a very specific attack with JSON requests that return data using [HTTP GET.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

By default, `MVC` framework does not allow you to respond to an `GET` request method with a `JSON` object, but, if you need to send `JSON` in response to a `GET` verb, you have to allow this using `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet`.