# AJAX and c# mvc controller get bool

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been stuck at this for some time now. I am trying to send a bool from my controller to the view through ajax. I tried several different tutorials and methods but can't seem to be able to retrieve some simple data. I was hoping somebody can explain what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    "url": "/social/checkfollow",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "success":function(data) {

        console.log(data);
    },
    "error": function(data) {
        console.log(data.status +" "+ data.statusText);
    }
});

});
```

And the controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult CheckFollow()
    {
        var pass = false;

        return Json(new {result = pass});
    }
```

For some reason i keep getting 500 Internal Service error. i know it's a really basic question and i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: remove  "dataType": "json", then try

Comment: I just did still the same error comes up...

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? If you debug the MVC app and add breakpoint to the CheckFollow method. Does it stop there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your return statement probably should be:

```
return Json(new {result = pass}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Pertinent explanation of the AllowGet: [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

Comment: thanks this solved it. and thank you for the explanation as well

Answer (score 2):

Return statement not properly for pass json so i have add sample code so try it and let me know any problem.

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult CheckFollow()
{
    var pass = false;

    return Json(new {result = pass}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```