# Sending Json with data with partial view

Tags: c#, json, ajax, partial-views

I have the following chtml code to an action in a controller.  The data is being sent by ajax to the action.
The chtml part:

```
<li>
    <button id="abandon-popup" onclick="Transfer(@Model.Id)">
       Transfer <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
    </button>
</li>
```

The function Transfer:

```
function Transfer(modelId) {
    //alert(modelId);
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "/Internet/Transfer",
        data: "id=" + modelId,
        success: function (responsedata) {
            alert("ok");
            window.location.href = responsedata.newUrl;
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log("KO");
        }
    })
}
```

The action in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Transfer(long id)
{
  *some actions*
  return Json(new { newUrl = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Leads/_TransferPopup.cshtml", commonModel) });
}
```

However I am getting a 500 internal error on this:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following:

```
return Json(new { newUrl = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Leads/_TransferPopup.cshtml", commonModel) });
```

into

```
return Json(new { newUrl = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Leads/_TransferPopup.cshtml", commonModel) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Change GET method to POST method the following way:

Client side:

```
function Transfer(modelId) {
//alert(modelId);
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/Internet/Transfer",
    data: {id: modelId},
    success: function (responsedata) {
        alert("ok");
        window.location.href = responsedata.newUrl;
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log("KO");
    }
})
}
```

Controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Transfer(long id)
{
  *some actions*
  return Json(new { newUrl = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Leads/_TransferPopup.cshtml", commonModel) });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Comment: MVC does not support return json data get method without JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. So you can change the method

Comment: change the method how?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  return Json(new { newUrl = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Leads/_TransferPopup.cshtml",
                             commonModel
                 )}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

> By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. If you need to send JSON in response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as the second parameter to the Json method. However, there is a chance a malicious user can gain access to the JSON payload through a process known as JSON Hijacking. You do not want to return sensitive information using JSON in a GET request.

Comment: Any other way of sending the data without the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet option?

Comment: If your action has the HttpPost attribute, then you do not need to bother

Comment: By the way, any reason for not to use it?  you can try with action-attribute further.  see this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718745/4153829

Comment: you can use this  : **[HttpPost]** public ActionResult Transfer(long id)

Comment: Now I getting error The resource cannot be found. with HttpPost.  Please help..  Ok it is not even hitting my action in the controller despite changing th etype from GET to POST in the transfer function.

Comment: Did you update ajax ?  

$.ajax({

       ** type: "POST", **