# How to insert data into a database using jQuery / Ajax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been stuck for hours trying to find the bugs when trying to insert data into database using ajax. When I click submit button, it just reloads but does not save. I am confused about this problem. I have searched many blogs but did not find accurate solution to this problem.

Model class

```
public class Semester
{       
    [Key]
    public int SemesterId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Semester Code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter semester code")]
    public string SemesterCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Semester Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter semeter name")]
    public string SemesterName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller 
             [HttpGet]

```
  public ActionResult SaveSemesterGet()
  {
    return View();
   }
   public JsonResult AsCreateSemester(Semester semester){


            db.Semesters.Add(semester);
            db.SaveChanges();


        return Json(semester, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

Index view:

```
      @model CampusManagementApp.Models.Semester
      <h2>SaveSemesterGet</h2>
      <form method="POST">

      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      <div >
        <h4>Semester</h4>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SemesterCode, new { @class = "control- 
     label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SemesterCode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SemesterCode)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SemesterName, new { @class = "control- 
   label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SemesterName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SemesterName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="SAVE"/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
<div>
    @*   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#btn").click(function(a) {

        a.preventDefault();
        var code = $("#SemesterCode").val();
        var name = $("#SemesterName").val();
        var jsonData = {
            SemesterCode: code,
            SemesterName: name
        };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AsCreateSemester", "Semester")',
             data:  JSON.stringify(jsonData),
               dataType:"json",


            success:function(data) {
                alert(data.SemesterName+"successfully inserted");
            },

            failure: function () {
                alert("not successfull");
            }

        });
</script>
```

What can be done to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Add the attribute `HttpPost` to the action you are using to post data.

Comment: You are executing the ajax call onload of window which happens before a user has a chance to interact with the page. Move that javascript to a function that you can call when the button is clicked.

Comment: not clear about your commnet ,what can be done @crowcoder

Comment: Disregard, I missed the part where you wired the click event. Did you try dougF's answer?

Comment: with regards,it dougF's answer does not work

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `db.Semesters.Add(semester);` and step through code(press F10) to check whether you are actually receiving data from page.

Comment: I have edited my above code and why it saves null value in a database@ Jaggan_j

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in the view:

1) You're subscribed to `click` event of a submit button without preventing default action which submitting the form. This triggered POST action which redirect away into the controller action and reload the page without leaving any time for AJAX function to execute. You should use `preventDefault()` to cancel the default action of the button.

2) The controller which receives AJAX callback does not have `[HttpPost]` attribute while `type: "POST"` option is used. Consider adding `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of controller name.

3) Your AJAX property names list does not match with property names defined inside model class. Consider using a viewmodel which accepts two properties and use it as action parameter.

Therefore, the AJAX callback should have setup as in example below:

**Viewmodel**

```
public class SemesterVM
{
    public string SemesterCode { get; set; }
    public string SemesterName { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="SAVE" />
```

**JS (click event)**

```
$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit

    var code = $("#SemesterCode").val();
    var name = $("#SemesterName").val();

    // all property names must be same as the viewmodel has
    var jsonData = {
        SemesterCode: code,
        SemesterName: name
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveSemester", "Student")',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSemester(SemesterVM semester)
{
    // add semester data

    return Json(semester);
}
```

Comment: Being updated code as above it saves null value in the database.

Comment: Using `ModelState.IsValid` doesn't make sense in AJAX callback. Also you're not including `HttpPost` attribute - this makes your AJAX call never reach the controller action which uses `GET`.

Comment: since I have used request behavior.allow get ,it is  necessary to add [httppost],i have seen many articles not use [httppost ] at the Json request, and modelstate is eliminated. Tetsuya Yamamoto

Comment: By default JSON data uses `POST`, if you want to allow `GET` operation then you need to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. Related: [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed).

Comment: i have run program as You say but it also save null values,is it occurs problem in ajax method? - Tetsuya Yamamoto

Comment: The null values occurred because the model binder didn't recognize passed values from JSON string or the request never reach the controller, which I already explained above. Note that the HTTP method and JSON property names matters there, make sure they're exactly match as defined in the viewmodel.

Comment: It returns correct value when i do not use JSON stringnify in data. passing the property value in data  it works ,answer is given-@Tetsuya Yamamoto

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a submit button?  Since the JS function you made is handling the post, you don't need to use a submit button, which is causing the entire page to reload.  Just use a normal button.

```
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="SAVE"/>
```

Comment: chanded the input type but it doees not respond and save the data.

Comment: When you debug, is the JS being fired at all?

Comment: @Talukder if the JS isn't being fired when you debug, you might also have to change how you wired up the button.  Instead of $("#btn").click(function() { maybe use $("#btn").on("click", function() { just in case for some reason the jquery isn't finding the button on page load.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the ajax() method like below it works.

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AsCreateSemester", "Semester")',

         data: {
             SemesterCode: code,
             SemesterName: name
         },



            success:function(data) {
                alert(data.SemesterName+"successfully inserted");
            },

            failure: function () {
                alert("not successfull");
            }

        });
```