# Success callback doesn't run when dataType is "json"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a list object from the server to an Ajax success callback, but I'm not receiving data in the console, and the `alert` calls in my code don't fire.

I don't have much experience with JS, and I haven't been able to determine why this isn't working. I've already tried changing `ActionResult` to `JsonResult`, to no avail.

This is the action method:

```cs
public ActionResult jason()
{
    var list = new CardModel().ItemList;
    return Json(list);
}
```

And this is the Ajax call:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/Card/jason/",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function myfunction(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var list = data;
        console.log(list);
        $.each(list, function(index, item) {
          alert(item);
        });
      }

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean, you get `undefined` in success callback ? or you do not get anything in console?

Comment: I get nothing .. not even undefined

Comment: Is it a typo?  Your URL is `/Card/jason/` - did you mean `/Card/json/`?

Comment: no,  my bad, it's misspelled here.. my Action name is "jason" actually not index

Comment: Try adding `error` callback.

Comment: @randomSoul   error message is : Internal Server Error

Comment: @Cavid - There is something wrong with your `backend` code. It has nothing to do with the `ajax` request. I mean with the `Get` request url route code.

Comment: @randomSoul when page loads I'm getting directed to url - CardController/jason. Inside there I retrieve the list and page finishes the load. So I can't see any error regarding server side.. Maybe I should install any Nuget package for Json serialisizing to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request 
you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet like

```
return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

see this link [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)
for details

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when your dataType is not correct.
Are you sure you're receiving JSON from the backend?

According to the docs:
[image]

You should be able to see an error in `error` callback function of `ajax()`

Comment: This means that the API you called has failed for some reason. You may want to debug your API. Your jQuery seems to be working fine.

Comment: could it return nothing(no console message or alert) if list count is 0?