# GET Request Blocked even though AllowGet is set in the controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting the following error returned intermittently from my several of my controllers:

> "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."

But in the return statement I do set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

```
return Json(new {Success = true, Plan = populatedPlan}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I found the following article which describes a vulnerability when returning JSON with GET Requests.

https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

I checked my code and some of the controllers were returning just a single JS array so I fixed those to return an object with the array assigned to a propery on that object. However, not all my controllers are doing this, like the one in my code snippet - that returns a JS object - but the response is still occasionally blocked.

How can I stop this error from happening?

**[Edit]** This is happening about 1 in every 200 requests. I'm just confused as to why it's happening when I'm already doing what the error message is explicitly telling me to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed

Comment: did you try to rebuild your project?

Comment: @HienNguyen The project compiles fine.

Comment: Can you post your controller and script to call to question

Comment: @Lennart - The issue is the same, yes, but the error message specifically tells me to specify AllowGet which I have done, and it still throws the error intermittently. If it blocked it every time it would be less of an issue but it's only happening every now and then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

Comment: I have the same issue (every once in a while) with large Json's... Like you, I already `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have another JSON return without `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` before reaching `return Json(new {Success = true, Plan = populatedPlan}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too,and i find out that my FilterAttribute blocked some request like this

```
  if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    IsAuthorize = false
                }                   
            };
        }
```

maybe you should check your FilterAttribute,and add AllowGet there too