# MVC POST is 404ing but if I change the POST to a GET, it works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

I have an MVC 4 application running on Kentico 11. I'm trying to make a new API endpoint for a node application to be able to hit it.

The method is structured as follow:

```
    [Route("api/SendEmail/projectEmail"), HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public JsonResult KioskEmailSubscribe(KioskEmailModel emailModel)
    {
           // code that doesn't matter because we don't get this far
    }
```

Whenever I use Postman to make a POST to this endpoint, it 404s. However, when I change the HttpPost to a GET (and remove the emailModel), it goes through just fine.

I tried changing it back to a POST (still without the emailModel) and it still 404s.  There's nothing fishy in my routeConfig as far as I know but I've attached it just to be safe:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("cms/{*pathinfo}");

        routes.Kentico().MapRoutes();

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // Catch-all routes (Anything not matching a specific route pattern will route to the default controller and be determined there)
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*route}", new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the CORS set? Also, what is your content type set to when you make the post, is it `plan\text`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your return.
The default setting of JsonResult doesn't allow client to send request with HTTP GET for system protection.

If you'd like to use HTTP GET, just make your return like this:

`return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

For more details and discussion, you can refer to: [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do actually have that, although the issue isn't with the HTTP GET, it's with the HTTP POST

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. I've noticed that your `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` is below the `MapRoutes`, maybe move it above?

Comment: Hmm nope, that didn't do it either. Thanks for the suggestion though