# e.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-ui

I have a kendoDropDownList using kendo UI and jquery. I have an error like this and don't know why I get this error.

```js
$("#drpState").kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "States...",
                delay: 10,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "StateId",
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            headers: {
                                "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                            },
                            type: "Post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/Supervision/Tracking/GetStates",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetStates(DataSourceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            request.Skip = 0;
            request.Take = 100;

            var states = await _stateService.GetStates(request, cancellationToken);

            return Json(states);
        }
```

[image]

the returned data is a DataSourceResult which contains Aggregates, Data and Total. Apparently, the Data has an array of objects as you see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @GaloisGirl I added that.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't say much. `e.slice()` is most probably `Array.prototype.slice()`, so something that is expected to be an array isn't. Does your back-end return an array?

Comment: @GaloisGirl Yes, Unfortunately, that doesn't say much.

Comment: Could your back-end do ` return Json(states.Data);` so it returns an array?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. But why it happened? could you please explain it to me? Because the error wasn't clear at all. I really want to learn from my mistakes and it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because Kendo expects an array from the request response, and its getting an object. You need to specify to Kendo where to find that array. Use [`schema.data`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemadata) on DataSource:

```
dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            headers: {
                "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
            },
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Supervision/Tracking/GetStates",
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Data"
    }
}
```

Or you can do like @GaloisGirl proposed and return an array directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but which approach is more secure? I mean is there a priority to use in case of security?

Comment: I think @DontVoteMeDown 's answer is a bit better, because the same back-end method can serve multiple front-end services, and you can say it's their job to adapt the data to their needs.
Or you could say since the back-end service has a plural name, it should return something plural: an array.
It's details, you'll be fine with either.

Comment: Additionally, we could use  `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the returned result previously as the second parameter to get a JSON format result, but now it omitted in ASP .Net Core because of security reasons called **JSON Hijacking** based on [JSON Hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) and [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277717/10589806](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277717/10589806) and now we need a pure collection of data includes of **key value** pairs to pass to KendoDropdownList. Am I right? @GaloisGirl @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: I don't use ASP.NET on my back-end and have no idea.

Comment: @siavashbashiri I think both ways are the same regarding security