# JSON-data get undefined as result. How to get JSON-data?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a dataset with location-data. And in the GetLocation the data are transformed in a latitude and longitude value. That works fine. But when I returned to the html-page. The data is undefined. What is the reason? And how can I resolve this with JSon-data?

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetLocation(Dictionary<string, string> items)
        {

                var result = "{ 'latitude': '" + latitude + "', 'longitude': '" + longitude + "'}";
                return Json(result);
            }
```

[image]

in the html:

```
    if (item.Location == null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetLocation", "Home")",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { items: item },
            type: "GET",
            success: (function (data) {
                location = JSON.parse(data);
            })
        });

        console.log("location:");
        console.log(location);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined"? What is in the `data` variable? Also, you're double-encoding the JSON here. The `Json` function in the action method is encoding the string as JSON. You could instead do `return Json(new { latitude, longitude });`

Comment: data is the input for the GetLocation-action. It's read as a Dictionary with keys and values. The output has to be an object with two values Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: I meant the data parameter in the `success` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are double-encoding the JSON here. The `Json()` function in the action method is encoding the string as JSON, which means the Javascript will be receiving something like this (note the quotes around the entire thing):

```
"{ 'latitude': '50.69093', 'longitude': '4.337744'}"
```

You should instead do something like this:

```
return Json(new { latitude, longitude }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now in your success function, you will be able to access the values:

```
success: (function (data) {
    location = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(location.latitude);
})
```

Note also the addition of `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed) for why that is needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is a part of the solution. I have added  contentType: "application/json", async: false, and cache: false in the Ajax-call. That works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please change like below

in MVC return type:

> return Json(new { result = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

in JQuery AJAX

> location = JSON.parse(data.result);

Comment: That is still going to double-encode the string as JSON, but now it's nested inside another object. This is only going to make things worse. So now it would return this `{"result":"{ 'latitude': '50.123', 'longitude': '4.123'}"}`